# PHP code to run UPDATE in MySQL table without returning out-of-range value

Tags: php, mysql

i am having a bit of a problem. I use the automated Dreamweaver programming features and built a form that dynamically updates a "volume" column in my MySQL table. This "volume" column holds values that i have to subtract from. I have been able to run the subtractions with a simple

```
UPDATE offers SET volume=volume-%s
```

and it works by returning:

> BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(`otcbb`.`offers`.`volume` - 2000)'

which i am very happy with.

The problem is that this script doesn't behave the same way when i upload it to my hosting server. When i run the query online it doesn't throw any errors and updates the table column with a new value: 4,294,967,295.

How can i get the same result online?

Locally i am running MySql version 5.0.8-dev and running MySql version 5.0.45.

I'd appreciate a timely answer.

Thanks

Comment: Are the table structures the same on both servers? Post them, please.

Comment: `UNSIGNED` - you can have only zero or positive values in this field

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have volume = 0 to begin with. 4,294,967,295 is 2^32 - 1 so you probably have an underflow somewhere.

Comment: @tombom The table values are the same in both environments. Yes UNSIGNED can only be a zero or positive value. I think its rather a limitation with the way MySQL handles integers and strings. I was able to solve the problem by using javascript function to control the user's input. Naturally, Jvascript will trigger error before processing on the server and the right value will always be entered into the input field. Thanks for the suggestions though, they are highly informative.